# Windows 8 Start Screen Shortcuts for Desktop Apps

Tags: windows-8, shortcuts, desktop, start-screen

I am facing an issue regarding Windows 8 shortcuts.

My app is not getting pinned for all users for the installed desktop apps.

If a user is installing that desktop app, then the shortcut of the app is getting pinned only for him, not for other users which were never faced with previous version of windows.

Can any one provide the reason for this issue or any reference for it?

Comment: Let me make sure I understand the question. When you pin an icon to the start screen, it only applies to one user and not everyone? This seems like normal behavior...

Comment: It isn't a drawback IMO. Start screen is supposed to be **your** screen. Hence, this is normal. If another user wants to pin it, he is free to do so

Comment: ya sure.. i have just installed one desktop application in my pc and autometically some shortcuts are pinned to the start screen, where as when i signed in as new user (this is the first time i am signed in to the pc after installing the application) the start screen is not displaying any shortcuts which are already installed in pc. but the same shortcuts are displaying in start screen when i signed in as other user which user has signed in to the pc at least once before the applications are got installed in the pc.

Comment: @PratyushNalam if isn't drawback then why start screen is not displaying shortcuts for a new user who signed in to the pc after the installation has done.

Answer (score 0):

*Right click* on the **Start Screen**

[image: Right click on Start]

*Click* **All Apps**.

[image: All Apps View]

You (and other users too) will see the desktop applications here. The All Apps section is the equivalent of the erstwhile Start menu and each user is supposed to customise the Start screen according to his wish by pinning apps he wants. So, I would say the start screen is the pinned applications view of the Start Menu and the all apps section is the Start Menu. Think of it, if you pinned something to the old Start menu in Windows 7, would you want it to be pinned for everyone? Most likely not

Comment: I know you are correct if it is the problem with manually pinned shortcuts.but here i'm talking about desktop applications shortcuts in start screen which autometically installed. here i am not manually pinning any shortcuts to the start screen. The installed  shortcuts are not displaying for some user (these some users haven't signed in before the shortcuts has installed) and those same shortcuts are displaying for some users (these some users are at least once they have signed in before the user installed shortcuts) on start screen. how windows 8 is differentiating the user's start screen.

Comment: It is only being pinned for you because you installed and the softwares haven't actually been updated to know that start all apps and start pinned apps are different. in some time no installation will pin apps i guess

Comment: @PratyushNalam: If you have 2 users, say User_1 and User_2, *who have both signed in at least once* (this is important) and User_1 installs a desktop (not Metro) app, does User_2 see tiles for the app on the main Start Screen, or only under All Apps? If the former, it seems to be a bug in Win8.

Comment: Only under All Apps

Comment: @PratyushNalam: That's the case even if User_1 is an admin and the app was installed for all users? Also, what Anna wants to know is, if you create a new User_3 and log in *for the first time*, does User_3 see the app installed by User_1 on either the Start Screen or under All Apps?